# Algorithm for finding if set of numbers can add up to X, with constrained histogram

Tags: algorithm, math

(Motivation: Consider a problem where you have to select a sports team from a population of available players.  Each player has a certain skill level exactly proportional to their salary expectation, and you want the total of this skill/salary level to exactly match your total salary cap.)

I need to write the following function:

```
 bool possibleAssignment(int N, int M, int T, vector<int> H);
```

The input constraints are:

- `0 < N <= 50`
- `0 < M <= 50`
- `0 < T <= 2500`
- `H.size() == N + 1`
- Forall `i`, `0 <= H[i] <= M`

possibleAssign returns true iff an array X of M ints can be assigned with the following three constraints:

1. Forall `i`, `0 <= X[i] <= N`
2. Forall `v`, the number of elements of `X` with value `v` is <= H[v]
3. The sum of X is T

By what algorithm or method can I implement possibleAssign?

Comment: Sounds like the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Except I don't believe Barcelona _has_ a salary cap. Which would make this problem much easier. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seems reduceable from the [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), or it is better known variant: [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which are NP-Hard, so there is no known polynomial solution for it.

However, it seems T is small enough, and luckily, there is a [pseudo polynomial solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_Programming_Algorithm) to the problem using DP.

Because the problem is already similar to the knapsack problem, **I'd try to reduce the problem to fit the knapsack problem**, and then invoke the DP algorithm for finding the best solution for the knapsack problem:

I'd first filter the list, keep only H[v] elements with value v. Now, set the elemets as follows:

```
value(x) = 1
weight(x) = x
Bag size = T
```

This will get you going - giving you the maximal number of elements that can be assigned with salary constraint T

Comment: Keep only H[v] elements with value v?  Taken literally this would mean to discard (set to zero) elements of H where H[i] == j and i != j.  I don't think this is what you mean?

Comment: And what do you mean "set the elements", set the elements of what?

Comment: elements = items in the knapsack problem, this solution reduces the problem to a knapsack problem and uses an existing solution to solve it.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: As far as I understood the problem: you can use only `H[v]` elements of value `v`. if you got `k > H[v]`, you will not use `H[v]-k` of them, so just drop them. By dropping I mean - do not add them as items to the knapsack algorithm which will be later invoked.